# What to make NReco work on pages that require authentication?

Tags: c#, nreco

I'd like to make several *pdfs* from pages that are sitting behind a login page. When I try doing the basic info from their page:

```
        var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

        htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFile("url-of-page", null, "export.pdf");
```

I get the page the site offers when you're not logged in.

And when I try giving it cookies (the site has 2):

```
        var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

        htmlToPdf.CustomWkHtmlArgs = " --cookie name1 value1";
        htmlToPdf.CustomWkHtmlArgs = " --cookie name2 value2";

        htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFile("url-of-page", null, "export.pdf");
```

I get the log in page. As if I've entered something wrong, but I get the cookies `1` to `1` from Postman.

Am I using a wrong format for the name and value?

I tried going through an `httpClient`, and the cookies work there and I get to the page, but I cant get the *pictures* and *css* when I do it like that.

Comment: I think It adds 2 different cookies. I'm not sure how to add them both on 1 line. Do you have an idea?

Comment: When you do `var s = ""; s = "bob"; s = "cathy";` What is the value of `s` after that? Similarly, what is the value of `htmlToPdf.CustomWkHtmlArgs` after assigning it twice?

Comment: That makes sense, I'm left with the problem of how to add 2 cookies on 1 line, do you have an idea what the syntax should look like?

Comment: hmm, for some unknown reason it works when I add just one of the 2 cookies, how does it work with just one of them however I don't know.

Comment: It was the sessionid, the other one was the username.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and "NReco" just had access to my login page . In the web config file of my project , my authentication setting was as below :

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

Then I add the name attribute to forms as it makes a session with the same name like this :

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="ACUID" loginUrl="/Login" protection="All" path="/" timeout="60" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

and finally again in my web config files in authorization setting I change it from :

```
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
```

TO :

```
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
```